# Why is the commutator subgroup of the group associated to a finite quandle finitely generated?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

A quandle $Q$ is a set with one binary operation $(x, y) \mapsto  x ∗ y$ which satisfies the following three axioms:

i) $\forall x \in Q: x ∗ x=x$

ii) the map $S_{x}: y \mapsto y ∗ x$ is a bijection on $Q$ for all $x \in Q$

iii)$(x∗ y)∗ z=(x∗ z)∗ (y∗ z)$ for all $x,y,z \in Q$

Given a quandle $(Q,∗)$, denote by $G_{Q}$ the group generated by all the elements of $Q$ and the set of relations
$x ∗ y = y^{−1}xy$  for all $x, y \in Q$.

I came across a theorem that said: let $(Q, ∗)$ be a finite quandle , then the commutator subgroup $G^{'}_{Q }$ of $G_{Q }$ is finitely generated. But why is that? I mean $G^{'}_{Q }= \langle g^{-1}h^{-1}gh|g,h \in G_Q \rangle$, but you still can generate infinitely many elements of $G_Q$ by using finitely many elements of $Q$. Can someone help me out?

Comment: @MattSamuel $G_Q$ is a quotient of a free group on finitely many generators. It may not be finite.

Comment: @MattSamuel There is no reason (in general) to believe that the commutator subgroup of a finitely generated group is finitely generated.

Comment: @MattSamuel the problem is that the theorem says that the number of commutators $g^{-1}h^{-1}gh$ is finite. Yet, these commutators belong to the group $G_Q$, which can have infinitely many elements.

Comment: I am confused because it seems to me that $G_Q'$ must actually be finite, but I have probably made a mistake somewhere. Axiom (ii) appears to imply that conjugation by any generator $x$ induces a permutation of the generating set $Q$ of $G_Q$. But then we get an induiced action of $G$ by conjugation on $Q$, and the kernel of this action lies in $Z(G_Q)$. So $|G:Z(G_Q)|$ is finite, which implies that $G_Q'$ is finite.

Comment: @Derek Did you ever find an error? The only place I see an issue is that I don't know how you drew the conclusion in the last sentence. Does $G$ even have elements of finite order?

Comment: @Derek Maybe the issue is that it's not that $[G:Z(G)]$ is finite, but $[G:{\rm Stab }\ x]$ is finite?

Comment: @MattSamuel It seems to me that the conjugation actions of the generators on the set $Q$ of generators define bijections, and so they induce an action of $G_Q$ on $Q$; that is a homomorphism $\phi:G_Q \to {\rm Sym}(Q)$, and elements in the kernel of this action, which has finite index in $G$, fix all elements of $Q$ and so lie in $Z(G_Q)$. The examples I have tried all have this property. In these examples $G_Q$ itself is torsion-free, but $G_Q/Z(G_Q)$ is finite.

Comment: @Derek But the derived subgroup can't be finite in a nonabelian torsion free group, correct?

Comment: @MattSamuel Sorry, the remark about $G_Q$ being torsion-free was wrong. In the example in the paper, $|Q|=3$ and $G_Q = \langle a,b,c \mid b^a=c, c^a=b, a^b=c,c^b=a, a^c=b,b^c=a \rangle$. Then $G_Q'$ is cyclic of order $3$, with $G_Q/G_Q'$ infinite cyclic. $Z(G_Q)$ has index $6$ in $G_Q$ and is the cyclic group generated by $a^2=b^2=c^2$.

Answer (score 1):

A quick Google search gave me this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1705.10607.pdf

Proposition 3.3 (2).

The title is "Automorphism groups of quandles and related groups" and it's by Bardakov, Nasybullov, and Singh.

Notice that in this case the commutator subgroup is generated by $ghg^{-1}h^{-1}$ for $g,h\in Q$. In general the commutator subgroup is the same as the *normal* subgroup generated by these elements, but the commutators of generators here are invariant under conjugation. Note that if $gag^{-1}a^{-1}$ and $hah^{-1}a^{-1}$ can be expressed this way, then
$$(gh)a(gh)^{-1}a^{-1}=g(hah^{-1}a^{-1})g^{-1}(gag^{-1}a^{-1})$$
Normally $g(hah^{-1}a^{-1})g^{-1}$ would not remain a product of commutators of generators, but in the enveloping group of a quandle it does. This makes the proof work.

Comment: That is indeed the paper I read.

Comment: @J.B I've edited my answer to explain.

Comment: This is certainly an easy argument that $G_Q'$ is finitely generated, but I have still not found any mistake in my argument proving it is finite.

Comment: It may be very specific for quandles, but somewhat more general groups presented as $\langle X \, | \, x_i^{x_j}x_k^{-1}\rangle$ with all generators conjugate is precisely class of fundamental groups of knotted orientable surfaces in $S^4$, and they're certainly not cyclic-by-finite in general.

Comment: Well, enveloping group of nontrivial three-element quandle is a trefoil group.

Comment: @MattSamuel, sorry for this late response, but why is the commutator subgroup generated by commutators $g^{-1}h^{-1}gh$, for $g,h \in Q$. Shouldn't it be the conjugates of such commutators?

Comment: @J.B My answer explains that. Conjugates of those commutators are still in that form.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I misread your answer my bad.

Comment: @MattSamuel just to make clear: are $g,h, a \in Q$?

Comment: @J.B No, not necessarily in the second part.

Comment: @MattSamuel i'm really confused right now. You say that in general the commutator subgroup is the same as the normal subgroup generated by commutators of elements in $Q$. But in general the commutator subgroup is generated by the conjugates of commutators of elements in $Q$.

Comment: @J.B Conjugates of commutators of elements of $Q$. By the way, that's what the normal subgroup generated by a set means. It's the smallest normal subgroup containing the set. In particular it contains all conjugates of the elements in the set, and it's not hard to see that these conjugates are sufficient to generate this normal subgroup.

Comment: @MattSamuel that's what I meant. I edited my comment. But still, you say that the commutators of elements in $Q$ are invariant under conjugation. Yet, you continue your proof with elements which are not necessarily in $Q$?

Comment: @J.B You should read it more carefully. I specify exactly what they are. $[g,a]$ and $[h,a]$ are products of commutators of elements of $Q$, and I express $[gh,a]$ in terms of their conjugates. It's the inductive step in a proof.

Comment: @MattSamuel okay, but then why does $g[h,a]g^{-1}$ remain a product of commutators of elements in $Q$ in the enveloping group?

Comment: @J.B Conjugation is a homomorphism so it's the same as conjugating all of the factors. $xyzx^{-1}=(xyx^{-1})(xzx^{-1})$.

Comment: And since all the factors of $[h,a]$ are commutators of elements in $Q$ and these commutators are invariant under conjugation, so $g[h,a]g^{-1}$ is a product of commutators of elements in $Q$.

Comment: @J.B $g[h,s]g^{-1}$, yes. I admit I skipped a few steps.

Comment: But still, we assumed that the commutators of elements in $Q$ are invariant under conjugation..

Comment: @J.B that's because elements of $Q$ and their inverses are invariant under conjugation. Again, conjugation is a homomorphism.

Comment: And that I don't get. How can you conclude this?

Comment: J.B $xyx^{-1}=x*y$

Comment: Yes, but this equality only holds for elements $x,y \in Q$. If you conjugate an element $x \in Q$ by an element $g \in G_Q$, then $ x \ast g$ makes no sense since $g$ is not necessarily in $Q$.

Comment: @J.B yes, but elements $x$ are products of elements of $Q$, and you're just applying the operation multiple times. $xyz(xy)^{-1}=x*(y*z)$.

Comment: Okaay, it all makes sense now! Thank you a lot for the clarification!

Comment: @J.B you're welcome

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty simple observation, really, and is true for more general class of groups.

Let $G$ be a group normally generated by single element $g_0$ and denote its conjugacy class as $X$. Then $G'$ is generated by elements $gg_0^{-1}$, where $g$ lies in $X$.

**Proof**: observe that $ H := \langle fh^{-1} \, | \, f, h \in  X \rangle$ is normal and factor $G/H$ is cyclic, therefore $G' < H$, but every element of the form $fh^{-1}$ is a commutator of two elements in $X$ because $X$ is a complete conjugacy class, so $H = G'$. Substituting $fg^{-1} = fg_0^{-1}(hg_0^{-1})^{-1}$ we obtain that $\mathrm {rk} \, G' \leq |X| - 1$.

In fact, our quandle is not always transitive, but anyway factor $G_Q/\langle fh^{-1} \,|\, f, h \in Q\rangle$ will be free abelian on orbits of $Q$, and for similar reasons kernel lies in commutator.